# Fabric using SSH key to connect the ec2 instance

Tags: python, ssh, fabric, ssh-keys

I'm learning the fabric to automatically connect the ec2 instance which is already created. I set a ssh_config in the ssh folder

```
Home myhostname
        Hostname 52.62.207.113
        User ubuntu
        UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
        StrictHostKeyChecking no
        PasswordAuthentication no
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey-pem
```

And I wrote a python file to test

```
from fabric import Connection
c = Connection('52.62.207.113')
result = c.run('uname -s')
```

The terminal response

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No authentication methods available.
```

I'm not sure what happens. I try to manually

```
ssh -i mykey.pem ubuntu@52.62.207.113
```

It is successfully connecting the EC2 instance

Answer (score 0):

```
Home myhostname
        Hostname 52.62.207.113
...
c = Connection('52.62.207.113')
```

I'm not a fabric user, but I guess you're expecting fabric to make use of the entry from your `ssh_config` file here? I can see two likely problems:

1. You have `Home myhostname`. The correct keyword here is `Host`, not `Home`:

   ```
   Host myhostname
           Hostname 52.62.207.113
   ```
2. If you want fabric to use the Host section for `myhostname`, you probably have to tell it to connect to `myhostname`:

   ```
   c = Connection('myhostname')
   ```

   You're telling it to connect to an IP address, and it probably wouldn't relate that to the host section

The actual error that you're getting, "No authentication methods available", is probably because fabric didn't apply the `Host` section from `ssh_config`, and it doesn't know of any key files that it should use for the session.

Comment: Home is one of the problems, and I found I should touch the config in the /.ssh not /ssh

Answer (score -1):

I think you missed `PreferredAuthentications` options.
And you typed your key file name incorrectly.

Change the config file as shown below and try connecting again.

```
Home myhostname
    Hostname 52.62.207.113
    User ubuntu
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey.pem
```